# how to create android autocomplete with 2 adapters?

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

[image]

[image]

how can i replace threshold(0) with adapter 1 to threshold(1) with another adapter?
please help..
this is my Code and it doesn't work:

```
String[] hashtag = {"Android", "Andaa", "Java", "XML", "OS", "SQL", "IOS"};
String[] hashtag_server = { "Ajax", "Php", "Javascript"};
```

and inside class onCreateOptionsMenu :

```
final SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete =
    (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)
    mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, hashtag);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, hashtag_server);

if(searchAutoComplete.getThreshold() == 0) {
searchAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
}else if(searchAutoComplete.getThreshold() > 0){
searchAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

Best regards..

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to achieve with 2 adapters with different thresholds ?

Comment: assumed: i wanna display tags like (#android, #apple)  in threshold(0), but in same case, for threshold(1), i wanna show autocomplete. And how can i do that? sorry for my bad english

Comment: Use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for your AutoCompleteTextView in beforeTextChanged check for the first letter, `getText().toString().length==0` then set different adaptor and change the threshhold else change the adaptor to previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lukman, please cek my code.

final SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

```
    // Retrieves the SearchView from the search menu item
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));

    // Assign searchable info to SearchView
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryText) {
            // Nothing needs to happen when the user submits the search string
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            ListContactBotFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });
```